# How to enable recording on Twilio Programmable Video

Tags: twilio

I see the docs on accessing recordings (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/recordings-resource), but I don't see any examples of actually setting up the recordings. Thanks.

EDIT: 
I see default settings can be configured here (https://www.twilio.com/console/video/configure), but how does one do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To use recording in Twilio Video you need to [create a group room via the REST API and set the `RecordParticipantsOnConnect` parameter to `true`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource#rooms-list-resource). The minimal code for this is:

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(api_key_sid, api_key_secret)

group_room = client.video.rooms.create(
  unique_name: 'RecordedRoom',
  type: 'group',
  record_participants_on_connect: true
)
```

You'd then need to join your participants to the room named "RecordedRoom" and they will be recorded.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: From one Phil to another, thanks. 

A follow-up question: how would I mute one user's tracks? I see how to do this for the Conversation API (https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/video/tracks#mute-one), but not sure what changes for the Rooms API.

Comment: Hey Phil! [To mute tracks you need to `disable` them](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.6.0/docs/LocalAudioTrack.html#disable__anchor). You can then `enable` the track again to unmute.

Comment: Great - thanks, @philnash. One more follow-up question on this, relating to status callbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179234/twilio-not-sending-status-callbacks

Comment: Hey Phil, I'm actually having trouble— I put up an SO post with my code. That's here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148499/setting-up-status-callbacks-for-twilio-video).

Comment: Sorry, I realize I linked to the wrong SO post— the right one's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148499/setting-up-status-callbacks-for-twilio-video

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense! I'll respond over there.

Comment: Phil, following-up with another question on muting audio tracks. That's here, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149631/muting-local-tracks-on-twilio-video