# Muting local tracks on Twilio Video?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Following guides, I'm attempting to disable and enable `localAudioTracks`.

Within the `roomJoined` function, I have these two functions:

```
      document.getElementById("audio-toggle-off").onclick = function() {
    console.log("muting this users audio");
    room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(trackId, track) {
      track.disable();
    });
  };

  document.getElementById("audio-toggle-on").onclick = function() {
    console.log("enabling this users audio");
    room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(trackId, track) {
      track.enable();
    });
  };
```

But on clicking these, I get the error that:

```
VideoChat.js:241 Uncaught TypeError: track.enable is not a function
at VideoChat.js:241
at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick (VideoChat.js:240)
```

Any ideas? For reference, I'm including the full `roomJoined` function below:

```
    function roomJoined(room) {
  window.room = activeRoom = room;

  log("Joined as '" + identity + "'");

  if (hide) {
    return;
  }

  // document.getElementById("button-join").style.display = "none";
  // document.getElementById("button-leave").style.display = "inline";

  // Attach LocalParticipant's Tracks, if not already attached.
  var previewContainer = document.getElementById("local-media");

  if (previewContainer && !previewContainer.querySelector("video")) {
    attachParticipantTracks(room.localParticipant, previewContainer);
  }

  // Attach the Tracks of the Room's Participants.
  room.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
    log("Already in Room: '" + participant.identity + "'");
    var previewContainer = document.getElementById("remote-media");
    attachParticipantTracks(participant, previewContainer);
  });

  // When a Participant joins the Room, log the event.
  room.on("participantConnected", function(participant) {
    log("Joining: '" + participant.identity + "'");
  });

  // When a Participant adds a Track, attach it to the DOM.
  room.on("trackAdded", function(track, participant) {
    log(participant.identity + " added track: " + track.kind);
    var previewContainer = document.getElementById("remote-media");
    attachTracks([track], previewContainer);
  });

  // When a Participant removes a Track, detach it from the DOM.
  room.on("trackRemoved", function(track, participant) {
    log(participant.identity + " removed track: " + track.kind);
    detachTracks([track]);
  });

  // When a Participant leaves the Room, detach its Tracks.
  room.on("participantDisconnected", function(participant) {
    log("Participant '" + participant.identity + "' left the room");
    detachParticipantTracks(participant);
  });

  // Once the LocalParticipant leaves the room, detach the Tracks
  // of all Participants, including that of the LocalParticipant.
  room.on("disconnected", function() {
    log("Left");
    if (previewTracks) {
      previewTracks.forEach(function(track) {
        track.stop();
      });
    }
    detachParticipantTracks(room.localParticipant);
    room.participants.forEach(detachParticipantTracks);
    activeRoom = null;
    document.getElementById("button-join").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("button-leave").style.display = "none";
  });

  document.getElementById("audio-toggle-off").onclick = function() {
    console.log("muting this users audio");
    room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(trackId, track) {
      track.disable();
    });
  };

  document.getElementById("audio-toggle-on").onclick = function() {
    console.log("enabling this users audio");
    room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(trackId, track) {
      track.enable();
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like this was able to work:

```
  document.getElementById("audio-toggle-off").onclick = function() {
    room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(
      audioTrack,
      key,
      map
    ) {
      console.log("muting this users audio");
      audioTrack.disable();
    });
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!