# Setting up status callbacks for Twilio Video

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm having trouble getting status callbacks working for Twilio Video. Here's where I create a room on the Ruby server:

```
    group_room = client.video.rooms.create(
      unique_name: room,
      type: 'group',
      record_participants_on_connect: true,
      status_callback: https://www.example.com/room_events,
      status_callback_method: 'POST'
    )
```

Note that this isn't just an issue of localhost not being accessible from the Internet— The problem occurs in production as well, with no signs of status callbacks occurring.

Comment: Is the `status_callback` an absolute URL?

Comment: It is; it's `https://www.example.com/room_events`

Comment: @philnash, any ideas?

Comment: I don't have any ideas I'm afraid. That should work and as I said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179234/twilio-not-sending-status-callbacks) I tried it myself and got the status callback. In this case I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide some Room SIDs where this didn't work so they can look into it.